# How a conflict is resolved in dynamic linking

Tags: dll, linker, global-variables, conflict

XYZ.dll defines a global variable int x.
ABC.c also defines the same global variable int x.
How can one link XYZ.dll to ABC.exe? How is this conflict in global namespace resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question, and I hope it gets a real answer. From what I can gather, a "global" symbol from a dll would have to be explictly imported via an associated header file. If you have two symbols that are the same, whichever symbol gets defined last, in the c file, is the one that would take precedence. That is, if you have ABC.c, and at the top, you would import XYZ.h, and then define int x. You either clobber the int x from XYZ.h, or you get a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

The variable int x has to be declared as extern int x in the header file of XYZ . And where ever you are going to use this variable just declare this variable.  Like in ABC.c in the global space declare this variable  like int x;